# Read single from file in C

Tags: file, curl

What i'd like to do is, read a single string of digits like "1234567890" from a file, and send it with curl to a server. i was hoping to find something like

```
token = readfile (myfile)

curl\"http://myserver.com/token/whatever
```

but it doesn seem that easy

Comment: `curl --data "@/path/to/filename" http://...`

Comment: Why is this tagged "C" ?